# How to handle pagination with JQuery and AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, get

On my site I have the links `First`, `Prev`, `Next`, and `Last`. These are empty links that are captured and handled by JQuery. However, still being very new to AJAX and JQuery, I'm not sure how to accomplish what I want. I believe I could get this working using [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) but the only problem is that I want the target page number to go in to the URL in this format:

http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?page=3

Then on page load I would use the $_GET variable and with the page number I could request the appropriate tables from the database and display them to the user.

Basically what I'm asking is how to make simulate [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp) behavior with JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Javascript:

post:

```
function pagination(page) {
    if (!page)
        var page = 1;

    $.post("index.php", { page: page }, function(data) {
        // data loaded, do something
   });
}
```

or get

```
function pagination(page) {
    if (!page)
        var page = 1;

    $.get("index.php?page=" + page, function(data) {
        // data loaded, do something
   });
}
```

Then, You just  have to call the javascript function:

```
<a href="javascript:pagination(1);">Prev</a> <a href="javascript:pagination(2);">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're requesting this from the same site as the script, you might be able to get away with this.

To load remote content (Google *Cross Site Scripting* for limitations), jQuery has a simple function to do that:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

This loads `test.html` into the item with the id of `#ajax`. Pretty simple.

In order to get the arguments, you can use this script (credit goes to http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html):

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

The usage information is avaliable there too.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something but how do I get that in the URL to begin with?

Comment: When jQuery does `$.get()`, it loads the page and *does not* parse the JavaScript on the loaded page. JavaScript is client side, not server side.